# Символ корня больше четвертой степени

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не знаю, как лучше сформулировать, и в какую степь копать: есть символы √, ∛,  ∜ а что делать, если мне нужно, скажем, корень пятой степени? Есть библиотека [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html), есть необходимость ее малость расширить, опыта в  javascript почти нет... как к этому лучше подступиться?

Comment: Использовать самодельный bitmap шрифт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

√^{6}3 не уверен но так должно отображать правильно или так √^6{3}